# Handling errors through exceptions

Tags: c++

I'm cleaning up my code and switching to error handling through exceptions (since this will shorten the code significantly in some places).

This means that I need to design my own hierarchy of exception classes.

Right now it looks something like this:

```
  namespace error
  {
  /** Generic error */
  class generic : public std::except
    {
    public:
      generic(const std::string& s) : std::except(s) {}
    };

  /** Namespace for network related errors */
  namespace network
    {
    /** Generic network error */
    class generic : public ::error::generic
      {
      public:
        generic(const std::string& s) : ::error::generic(s) {}
      };

    /** Network timeout */
    class timeout : public ::error::network::generic
      {
      public:
        timeout(const std::string& s) : ::error::network::generic(s) {}
      };
    }
  }
```

The problem is that this doesn't look particularly readable. Is there some preferred style when dealing with hierarchies of exception classes?

Comment: This looks fine to me. If I were you, I'd just simply remove the `::error` and `::error::network`, as they are not necessary in these cases (if I'm not misreading something)

Comment: I agree with what @KirilKirov has said, but I also don't see much reason for the `generic` class.

Comment: You probably meant `std::exception`, not `except`, and that has some pure virtual member functions that you will need to implement. Make sure that your exception object complies with the exception guarantees that it needs to (in particular, copying should **not** throw an exception. Having a `generic` error and a `generic` network exceptions seems a bit off...

Comment: Which one exactly? `error::generic` or `error::network::generic`?

Comment: personally, I wouldn't rely on the "error" namespace to describe the fact that these classes are errors: `using namespace error;` could easily make the class `generic` seem pretty unclear, and goes against the rule of naming types nouns. But that's just a code style thing.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yeah, this is minimal example.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yup, it's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class name doesn't describe the role it's going to have, that's a sure sign that the class shouldn't exist. You have two classes called `generic`. What is the point of them?

Really, you have only introduced one exception type, `timeout`. I would rewrite what you have given as simply:

```
namespace error
{
  namespace network
  {
     class timeout : public std::exception 
     {
       public:
         timeout(const std::string& s);
         const char* what();
     }
  }
}
```